# Dynamically created links only work once after using replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I am dynamically creating a list from an array of objects called "data". For each element in the array, I create a list object 'li' with a link. This list
will be appended to a div called  "information" at the end. While creating the link, I add an event listener that on clicking, will save the 
current contents of the div and change the content of the div to some additional info (shows the name and the state) about the list item I clicked. It also adds a button called
'go_back' that restores the list using replaceWith() function.

```
ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.className = "list";

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{   
   var li,link,text;
   li = document.createElement('li');
   text = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
   link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = "#"+ data[i].name;
   link.appendChild(text);
   li.appendChild(link);
   link.addEventListener("click", description, false);
   ul.appendChild(li);

   function description(){
    var $saved = $('#information').clone(true,true);
    $("#information").html('<p>Name: ' + data[i].name + '</p>' + '<p>State: ' + data[i].state + '</p>' + '<p><button class="btn btn-danger" id="go_back">Go Back</button></p>');

    $('#go_back').on('click',function(){
        $("#information").replaceWith($saved);          
    })
  }
}
document.getElementById('information').appendChild(ul);
```

However, this works well when I click on the list item for the first time, i.e., it changes the content of the div with the info about the list item I click and
on clicking 'go_back', the div shows the list again. However, the links don't work anymore after this. I tried the .on() function as suggested for similar issues
in stack overflow by assigning an id to the link, but this does not work (I click on one of the list items and it continuously shows the info for all list items).

P.S. I have made the list expandable and collapsible, the code for that follows the last line. The go_back button is able to restore the exact state of the expanded
and collapsed items (after passing true,true in clone function). I had problems when using .html() instead of replaceWith() and hence didn't use .html().

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by using .on function. Since I am new to javascript and jquery, I was not aware that I could use javascript variables in jquery. Attaching 'on' function on the 'link' variable solved the problem!